# Fancy, interactive GUI for a c++ game

Tags: html, flash, user-interface, awesomium

I'm trying to make quite a complex game (open source for windows, using dx11, c++) and I'm looking for a GUI library that is designed for using in games (I don't care about layouts but rather about customized look). I tested out QT, CEGUI and many others but they didn't fit my requirements. When I found Scaleform I started to search for free alternatives such as Awesomium that have the ability of rendering flash or html5 content. So there I have a couple of questions:

1. Is it better to use 'normal' GUI frameworks like QT or CEGUI? What about Intermediate GUI systems, are they Ok in games? The most important for me is that the lib should give me control of the main loop.
2. What do you think about the other solution (Awesomium)? Is it sufficient that I simply make a *.swf file and import it to my game? This would also give a possibility of creating 3d interface, am I right? Finally if you recommend me to use Awesomium, what should I use- Flash (I have some experience with it) or html5 (I don't know anything about it but learning js shouldn't be a problem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the following [PDF](http://quitcoding.com/download/Qt_Quick_Game_Programming_1_0.pdf)

It is a tutorial on QML, a Qt based framework used for games. If you have past experience with Qt, it should be a breeze. You would be better off knowing JavaScript for this though.

Flash would also be a good option, but if you want your GUI game to work on an iPad, then you will have trouble. If you are in fact planning to distribute your game on iPad, then HTML5 would be a better choice than Flash (since Apple randomly decided not to use Flash).

QML will also allow you to make 3D games.

If you want more professional game development (including hosting the game on a website), you can take a look at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). It is usually associated with C#, which is similar to C++.

About Awesomium, you are better off using HTML5, as Flash is in its decline stage of its life cycle. If you are ok with buying a license for Awesomium, then go with that. You should know if you plan to distribute you game and you need to know how much money you will be making (if any). If it is less than $100,000, then you can distribute the game for free and don't need a paid license.

Unity,

[image]

Awesomium,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**1.**
CEGUI was originally made as a GUI library for games, which is what you are looking for. It can also be used for any other kind of application, as well as for any rendering application, as it is a robust, active and feature-rich library.

You said CEGUI and Qt do not match your requirement. Could you specify this further?

CEGUI can easily be enhanced and be used with Direct3D, OpenGL, Ogre Engine, Irrlicht Engine, and can also be integrated into any other Engine using OpenGL or Direct3D. Also, you can customise the looks of your UI elements using XML. Look n' Feel XML files allow you to create your own UI elements, and also to skin them. Layout files allow you to separate each page of a game menu into a different file, or you can make a different view for each type of user interface, or separate subsections of your UI into different files. These files can be edited using the CEED editor, which easily makes it possible to create layouts, add your elements and align them. This process might not be as intuitive as in Flash, however it takes less performance and CEGUI already has a rich set of different types of widgets. Also it is easily enhancable since you have access to the full C++ code and an active community.

Keep in mind that when using a half-baken new GUI library, you might at some point reach a point where you miss a feature and aren't able to add it. With Qt and CEGUI this is most likely not the case because these projects exist for a very long time and can be adjusted to your needs. Also keep in mind that CEGUI and Qt are for free. CEGUI has the MIT license so you are only required to include a license file into a folder of your final game, that's all.

**2.** Using flash and html is definitely an easy way to create GUIs. However, if a UI library has an editor, this might be a sufficient solution for you as well. Qt has an WYSIWYG editor which works fine. CEGUI has that as well, although it is still missing an editor for skinning widgets(something you probably want to do). The Skinning Editor for CEGUI (CEED) is currently being made but it might take some months until it will be released.

I hope this information helps you.

Answer (score 1):

What i suggest is something that put you in condition of using flash/html5.

Take a look to http://coherent-labs.com/

I'm using it in my personal project ( PC platform ).

Comment: I've seen that and it's even more awesome (that on-demand view..), but as far as I understand it is only 30 days trial, right? (and is pretty expensive [link](http://coherent-labs.com/native-pricing/) )